# Duplicate symbol show with Xcode8

Tags: duplicates, symbols, xcode8

- my project running was fine yesterday, but after update Xcode8, same project can't build with this error:

[libUMSCashierPlugin.a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U96YE.png)

I have try `lipo` and `ar`, nothing working, and when I build with Xcode7.3.1, nothing happen, no warning, no error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code recommended to use warning flags and set GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS to YES.

Setting it back to NO solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I declared "static const" for variable instead of "const"

You may use const variable like below.

```
NSString *const OPERATECODE_GET_AID = @"{SOMETHING}";
```

I recommend to change like this.

```
static NSString *const OPERATECODE_GET_AID = @"{SOMETHING}";
```